# Not a known element in angular even when using NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have and Angular Popup Component used as follows ([Online Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwpun3)):

```
<popup>
  <anchor>
    Menu        
  </anchor>
  <window>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>           
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </window>
</popup>
```

An the component template is:

```
<a class="anchor" (click)="toggle()">
  <ng-content select="anchor"></ng-content>
</a>
<div class="window" [hidden]="!active">
  <ng-content select="window"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Template parse errors: 'anchor' is not a known element:    
1. If 'anchor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.    
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

The Popup Module already has NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { PopupComponent} from './popup.component';

@NgModule({  
  declarations: [PopupComponent],      
  imports: [CommonModule],  
  exports: [PopupComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class PopupModule {}
```

And the PopupComponent is:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html'
})

export class PopupComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean = false;
  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You placed the `anchor` element in `AppComponent` template. **`AppComponent` is defined in `AppModule`**.

So add `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to that module:

```
@NgModule({  
  ...
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw96qi?file=src/app/app.module.ts)**

Comment: I see ... I misunderstood it. I though NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA was for the module defining the component but it is for the module using the component. So probably this is a bad idea because I would need to have NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in all places where this component is used correct?

Comment: Having NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA is only encouraged in tests. Why do you want to use such tag?

Comment: `I would need to have NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in all places where this component is used correct?` Since Angular is looking for transitive module scope when compiling templates then you have to add it to each of your modules where you have a component that has that tag in template

Comment: I just decided to use an attribute. Thank you for the help and explanation. Just marked as answer